# Adding extra fields to WordPress Navigation menus

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way I can add extra fields to the WordPress Navigation menus? I know you can Add a description, but what about adding other fields?

Answer (score 0):

What other fields do you want besides those supplied in the admin? Nav menus only have:
 - Name
 - Link
 - Link title

Comment: I'm writing a translation plugin, so I need to write translations for each of the Navigation menu elements. That's why I need extra fields.